# Como generar carpeta /lib desde maven a un proyecto JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, maven

En NetBeans es facil crear un proyecto JavaFX o Swing y exportar el Jar, pues NetBeans crea la carpeta lib con todos los Jar que se usaron en el proyecto.

Necesito realizar el mismo procedimiento pero usando Maven e Intellij.
Generar el Jar ejecutable y la carpeta con las librerias que se usaron como dependencias en el pom.xml

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solucion fue instalar un plugin. Adjunto El codigo pom.xml de mi proyecto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>prueba</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DigitalPerson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalperson</groupId>
            <artifactId>dpfpenrollment</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalperson</groupId>
            <artifactId>dpfpverification</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalperson</groupId>
            <artifactId>dpotapi</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalperson</groupId>
            <artifactId>dpotjni</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- EMPAQUETA TODAS LAS LIBRERIAS EN UN SOLO JAR -->
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.systemnecs.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

**con maven-dependency-plugin**
Solo falta especificar la ruta de destino en `<outputDirectory>"ruta de destino"</outputDirectory>`donde copiara todas las librerias que se declaran en el pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                   "ruta de destino"
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu etiqueta "dependency" añade lo siguiente:

```
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/SomeLibrary.jar</systemPath>
```